# Are there any compilers for compiling Racket to C?

Tags: c, scheme, racket

### Original Question

I am developing a programming language as a side project. I am also learning Racket as well.

I have come half way through the project, but I am struggling to compile Racket to C.

I have looked at Racket's documentation for [compiling native code via C](https://download.racket-lang.org/docs/5.1/html/raco/ext.html) and it states that:

> The `--c-source`/`-c` mode for `raco ctool` is like the `--extension/-e` mode, except that compilation stops with the generation of C code.

I have been trying to use the `--c-source` mode for a while, but I get a error saying that `--c-source` is an invalid mode.

This is how I've written my command:

```sh
raco ctool --c-source emit.rkt
```

Any help will be appreciated.

---

### Updated question

Since `--c-source` was part of an earlier version of Racket, my question has changed a bit..

I am trying to search for a Racket to C compiler for the **latest** version of Racket.

I have seen two repositories on GitHub for a Racket to C compiler, but the last commit for those repositories is more than two years ago.

Comment: It does not appear this functionality is in the current version of the Racket distribution (7.2 as I write this).  If you really need this, it looks like the latest Racket version to support this option was 5.1.3, which may be downloaded here: https://download.racket-lang.org/racket-textual-v5.1.3.html  Note however that there may be other major differences between that and your current version

Comment: @Shawn, are there other programs that can compile Racket to C?

Comment: Your question has changed from "why doesn't this work?" to "How do I do this thing?"... but in this case, that could mean a HUGE number of different things. One trivial way: given a Racket program, emit a C program that pipes the given text to a file, then invokes racket on it. I'm guessing that's not what you want, but your question is (now) very underspecified.

Comment: I'm guessing this is/will be possible in the latest version of Racket via the Chez Scheme backend https://blog.racket-lang.org/2019/01/racket-on-chez-status.html there appears to be an `--enable-cify` option https://github.com/racket/racket?path=racket/src